# HTML Javascript Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple form on my website where it ask the user for their email and the city they're located in like this:

[image]

I'm using EmailJS (emailjs.com) and MailJet (mailjet.com) services and while EmailJS and MailJet are doing their jobs, I'm ultimately not able to view the actual form data such as the email and city that was enter anywhere on MailJet, EmailJS or emails that are sent to me. I'm new to web development.

Here's my html code:

```
<form class="form-inline" type="text" onsubmit="emailjs.sendForm('mailjet', 'myTempNameFromEmailJS', this); return true;" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="contactUsEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="contactUsEmail" placeholder="City">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary contactUsButton">Signup</button>

</form>
```

What in the world am I doing wrong? I've essentially been working on this since yesterday and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you have `type="password"` for the city? Wouldn't users want to see what they are typing?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't make the change to 'text' yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the emailjs docs at https://www.emailjs.com/docs/api-reference/emailjs-sendform/ the third parameter of the sendForm method should be "form_id", the **id** of the form used to collect the parameters. Currently you're sending "this", but that's the variable which (in that particular context) holds the JavaScript representation of the whole form element.

I think you should change it to `this.id`:

```
emailjs.sendForm('mailjet', 'myTempNameFromEmailJS', this.id);
```

Comment: Thanks you. I think I have it figured out now.

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with mail jet, however, usually to gain the values out of your forms you need to add the name attribute, for example

```html
 <input type="email" class="contactUsEmail" placeholder="Enter email" name="contactUsEmail"/>
```

name="contactUsEmail"/>

Comment: Thanks you. I think I have it figured out now.